# bibtex not finding .bib file in Windows 10 using WinEdt

Tags: biblatex, templates, thesis

In the code below using the FAU Thesis template found [here](http://physics2.fau.edu/%7Ecbeetle/FAUThesis/#links), my Bibliography is not getting generated.  I have the chapters.bib file in folder named "References".

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[phd, 12pt, print]{fauthesis}

\usepackage{lipsum}


%======================================================================================
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%======================================================================================
\usepackage[backref=false,
            defernumbers=true,
            style = ieee,
            %sorting=none,
            sortcites=true,
            backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{../References/chapters.bib}% BibTeX
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}

%%% Bibliography Formatting
%
% This modifies the default LaTeX thebibliography environment to:
%   appear in the table of contents, and
%   list individual items single-spaced.
%
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
    \chapter*{\bibname\@mkboth{\bibname}{\bibname}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}%
    \begin{singlespace}
    \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth\advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}\let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
        \sloppy  \clubpenalty4000  \@clubpenalty\clubpenalty  \widowpenalty4000%
        \sfcode`\.\@m}
    {\def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
        \endlist\end{singlespace}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-3]\cite{Richardson}

%\phantomsection
\begin{singlespace}
\setlength\bibitemsep{10pt}   % length between two different entries
\printbibliography
\end{singlespace}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}\bibname}

\end{document}
```

I keep getting the errors:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.1)
The top-level auxiliary file: biblo.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file biblo.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file biblo.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file biblo.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

This used to work up to early last year, now I cannot get my bibliography to compile properly.  Can you assist me in getting my bibliography to be generated?  Thanks!

Comment: Your code needs you to run Biber (`backend=biber`), but your editor runs BibTeX for you (`This is BibTeX`). Configure your editor to run Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: @moewe, Thanks for your reponse.  That was the solution!